# Empty string in Alamofire parameters as null

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

I make a `POST` call with string from search text field to get some values. For example I `POST`:

```
["Term" : Gre]
```

And I get:

```
[Green, Grey]
```

In my functionality, if I pass three spaces I get first 20 values. But when I pass three spaces to Alamofire parameters:

```
["Term" :    ]
```

I get an error that `"Term"` value is `null`. How should I pass the empty string to Alamofire params to keep it as an empty string?

Comment: `["Term" : "   "]` You mean that?

Comment: It should be. But when I print params it shows me ["Term" :    ] ([String : AnyObject])